# PHP mail retrieving the address from SQL query

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a little program for logging IT issues internally. I want to add email functionality so that if an engineer assigns an issue to another engineer it will generate an email to them.

If I hardcode an email address into the `$to` variable it works, but I want to get the eamil address from a SQL table. In this instance it is from engineers.

```
$emailresp = "select email from engineers where name =('".$_POST["responsible"]."')";
$email = sqlsrv_query($conn, $emailresp);
$to = sqlsrv_fetch_array($email) ;
```

I have narrowed it down to the statement above, I am just not good enough to troubleshoot it. The idea is to have the `$to` to be a single email address.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). And **HOW** is this not working?

Comment: Need more debug - are you sure the query is even executing to the point of putting content into $email?

Comment: Solved. It was not populating the $to variable with the email address.

Answer (score 0):

The code was not populating the $to variable with any data, and was infact not getting that far in the process.

Looking at the PHP documentation i amended to code to look like:

```
$emailresp = "select email from engineers where name =('".$_POST["responsible"]."')";
$email = sqlsrv_query($conn, $emailresp);
$eresult = sqlsrv_fetch_array($email, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
$to = $eresult['email'] ;
```

Now the $to variable correctly stores the email address to be used in the mail function later in the script.